# How can I convert pinescript NZ to Python?

Tags: python, pandas

df['test'] = value

df['ama'] = NZ(df['ama'].shift()) + df['test']

How conver NZ(PineScript) to Python

fillna(0), but does'n work

Answer (score -1):

df['ama'] = df.test.cumsum()

it's works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).